# Any way to inject/choose datasource at runtime?

Tags: annotations, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, cdi

I have a MySQL database with many databases, each named for a specific customer.

A webapp is deployed per customer. The name of the webapp determines the underlying database name. When the webapp starts up, I have a modified Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to grab the ServletContext if it can and determine the name. I then dereference this in my datasource setup. Works beautifully. The exact same code can be deployed to all customers and they find their database without issue (also a DNS name to locate the MySQL host).

I'd like to switch to GlassFish or JBoss AS 6 and still do the same thing with straight JEE6 API/annotations.

Is there a way to do this? I'm not worried about security -- the datasets are large enough to justify their own machines and webapps and since the database model is tied to the code, they need to be kept in sync. Since not every customer needs to have the latest code for the task at hand, they revision at different rates.

I like the convenience of JEE6 consolidating a lot what Spring used to have and then some but I hate having to deal with application servers and their idiocy but cobbling together Spring isn't fun either.

Comment: So you want JPA to pick a datasource at runtime? But how are you  using it? Container-managed entity manager? I'm not sure there are enough details to give an answer...

Comment: Yes, I would like to use container-managed JPA. I've seen the @DataSourceDefinition annotation which I could not get to work under JBoss AS 6Mlatest for the life of me.

http://blogs.sun.com/Lance/entry/introducing_the_datasourcedefinition_annotation

Could I have an EJB load at startup time that determines the app name and registers the JNDI datasource? Hopefully without having to use vendor extensions.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to switch to GlassFish or JBoss AS 6 and still do the same thing with straight JEE6 API/annotations.

I'm afraid this won't be possible. To my knowledge, with a container-managed entity manager, you won't be able to configure its underlying datasource at runtime.